“mysql_secure_installation” asks for root password on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 but no password is set. What to do?
On a brand new installation of mysql on RHEL 8, I'm not asked at any point to set a root password. When I run mysql_secure_installation, it asks for the password for user root. I don't have that password, and leaving it blank doesn't work either.
I checked this question first, but it doesn't seem to solve my problem. Running the command with sudo makes no difference, and /var/log/mysql/mysql.log don't exist for me to check the temporary password.
How can I set this password on initial setup? mysql -u root --skip-password, sudo mysql, and using an init file have all failed as well.

Update: This question has a solution that involves using an init file, which I've already stated has failed.

hm. what commands did you run under sudo mysql? I've set a password before as per https://ghost.org/docs/install/ubuntu/#install-mysql and it worked. I'm wondering if the same would work.

I just get access denied when I try to do sudo mysql.

Is SETTING a root password a viable option? Please add more detail regarding the steps you've tried from the linked answer. I don't see anything about INIT files either, and I see commands other than sudo mysql that need to be run. Please go through those steps carefully and list the output for each in your question here to help us better understand how your question differs.

This question is similar to: How can I reset my MySQL root password in MySQL 8.0.36 on Red Hat 8 if ‘mysqld_safe’ is gone?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


“When I run mysql_secure_installation, it asks for the password for user root. I don't have that password, and leaving it blank doesn't work either.”

That's because you don’t have a root user password set. Follow these steps to get a root user password set with MySQL 8.0
First thing to know is the older mysqld_safe method doesn’t work… Details below.
The mysqld_safe (binary/shell script) is definitely no longer a part of the MySQL 8 package (8.0.36) in Red Hat 8 and possible other Linux distros.
It might be gone (as a binary/shell script) from the MySQL install on systemd managed systems since at least MySQL 5.7.6 according to this other answer on Stack Overflow:

“As of MySQL 5.7.6, for MySQL installation using an RPM distribution, server startup and shutdown is managed by systemd on several Linux platforms. On these platforms, mysqld_safe is no longer installed because it is unnecessary. For more information, see Section 2.5.10, “Managing MySQL Server with systemd”.”

Regardless of the reason, if you get this message when attempting to run mysqld_safe:
mysqld_safe: command not found

And your system runs systemd (aka: systemctl) then this is definitely the modern answer that will solve your problems in 4 easy steps! Here we go!

Stop mysqld and restart it with the proper MYSQLD_OPTS:
sudo service mysqld stop;
sudo systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-grant-tables --skip-networking";
sudo service mysqld start;


Once MySQL has started, login to MySQL as root with no password:
mysql -u root;


Now, in MySQL run these commands; note that [password] should be changed to whatever MySQL password you want it yo be set to:
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY '[password]';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;

Note, I believe the first FLUSH PRIVILEGES; is connected starting up MySQL with the MYSQLD_OPTS set to --skip-grant-tables. Regardless, running FLUSH PRIVILEGES; doesn’t pose any risk/danger.
Now, roll back the MYSQLD_OPTS and restart MySQL as follows:
sudo service mysqld stop;
sudo systemctl unset-environment MYSQLD_OPTS;
sudo service mysqld start;



Now with all that done, try to login to MySQL as root with a password like this:
mysql -u root -p

Hit Enter/Return, then enter your newly set root password and… et voilà! You should be logged into MySQL as root!

Note: I chose to set the password with caching_sha2_password authentication plugin, but if you want to be more modern, you can use mysql_native_password as follows:
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '[password]';

